# org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress not found on Elasticsearch 6

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-6

My code is working fine in elasticsearch 5 but when I have upgraded from 5 to 6 then. it is showing

```
org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress not found
```

complete stack trace:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project elastic-store: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/elastic/elastic-store/src/main/java/com/qw/psence/store/es/common/ESClient.java:[12,42] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class InetSocketTransportAddress
[ERROR] location: package org.elasticsearch.common.transport
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
```

can anyone help me to resolve this problem?

Note: Elaticsearch jar is fine.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Elastic search 6.0 has removed **InetSocketTransportAddress**  class. I have solved this By replacing **InetSocketTransportAddress** class with **TransportAddress** class.

```
// on startup

TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
        .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("host1"), 9300))
        .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("host2"), 9300));

// on shutdown

client.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions offered to the problem, but I was getting this error because, as I was trying to make a basic elasticsearch configuration with SpringBoot:

**I forgot to start elasticsearch...**

**:facepalm:**

So, just:

1. open command line at `bin` folder in your Elasticsearch installation directory*
2. type `elasticsearch`
3. press Enter

To make sure it works, open `http://localhost:9200/` in your browser. You should get a JSON response containing name, cluster_name, elasticsearch version etc.

*(On Windows) Open `ES_INSTALLATION_DIR\elasticsearch-x.x.x\bin` folder, hold Shift key, right click on the folder area and from the drop-down menu select `Open command window here`.

Answer (score -1):

In my case the issue was conflicting version of the elasticsearch that was pulled into my project by the `spring-boot-dependencies`. If your pom does not inherit from the `spring-boot-starter-parent` but instead uses `dependencyManagement` section to import `spring-boot-dependencies` and you need an older version of the elasticsearch on the classpath then here is the solution: [InetSocketTransportAddress](http://itzap.com/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-elasticsearch-common-transport-inetsockettransportaddress/). Always run `mvn -Dverbose=true help:effective-pom` and inspect effective pom for conflicts. `-Dverbose=true` is critical here. It allows to see where the unwanted dependency is coming from.